# The GitLens "Branches" view in VSCode w/ GitLens plugin is always out-of-date with remote

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I've been using GitLens for quite some time in VSCode, but the GitLens "Branches" view seem to *always* be out-of-date. Any time I need to check out a branch from one of my developers, I *always* have to run the following command first before seeing it appear in the Branches view:

```
for i in `git branch -a | grep remote | grep -v HEAD | grep -v master`; do git branch --track ${i#remotes/origin/} $i; done
```

This is super inconvenient, requiring me to do this pretty much daily to stay up-to-date with what's going on in the remoter branches.

Is there any way to configure Git or GitLens to auto-track all remote branches, during one of the Git calls?

Comment: remote branches are listed in the `Remotes` section of the "Source control" view ; is that what you are looking for ?

Comment: Unbelievable. Have been using the plugin for 6 months and never realized this. Thanks so much. Smh